# how to refuse save if the text only contain " "

Tags: vb.net

I need code to refuse save the text to database if the text contain only space " " ?

I tried this but it work with one space

```
        If NameSearchTB.Text.Contains(" ") Then

        MsgBox("you have to type something", vbInformation, "Movies Store")

        Exit Sub
    Else End If
```

Comment: `If NameSearchTBText.Trim.Length = 0 Then...` or `if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameSearchTB.Text) Then,,,,` or ,,,,,,etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally be handling the `Validating` event of a control if you want to validate its contents. That way, you can prevent the user shifting focus away from the control until they enter valid data. In your case:

```vb
Private Sub NameSearchTB_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles NameSearchTB.Validating
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameSearchTB.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name to search for",
                        "Movie Store",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When it comes time to use the data, you know that every control that has received focus must be valid. To validate those that haven't received focus, you call the form's `ValidateChildren` method. It will raise the `Validating` event for every control and thus every control, including those that haven't received focus, will be validated. `ValidateChildren` returns `False` if any `Validating` event was cancelled and `True` otherwise, indicating whether it is safe to go ahead and use the data.

```vb
If ValidateChildren() Then
    'All data is valid so use it safely here.
End If
```

There's no need to display an error message because the `Validating` event handlers will take care of that.